# New/old space in $M_{k}(N,\chi)$, $M_{k+1/2}(N,\chi)$, when $\chi$ is primitive

Tags: modular-forms

Let $M_k(N,\chi)$ be the space of modular forms with integer weight $k$, level $N$ and Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $N$. Further assume that $\chi$ is primitive. Why there are no oldforms in this space?

Attempt: Let $M|N$ and $d|(\frac{N}{M}).$ If $f\in M_k(M),$ then $f(dz)\in M_K(N),$ and $f$ is an 'old' form for the space $M_k(N)$. In a similar fashion when a Drichlet character $\chi$ is introduced, if $f\in M_k(N,\chi)$, then it cannot come from a 'lower' space $M_k(M,\psi)$ - because $\chi$ is primitive and it cannot be decomposed to get a 'lower'  $\psi$. I know I am being vague here, still is this correct or missing something?

In a similar way, does the space $M_{k+1/2}(N,\chi)$ consists only of newforms when $\chi$ is primitive (modulo $N$)?

Comment: The first part is correct. It's simply the definition of old forms. The second part (for half integer weight) looks strange to me, since half integral weight modular forms don't have central characters in general. They correspond to representations of the metaplectic group, so only have a quasi central character.

Comment: @WhatsUp I am not familiar with central characters or how do they relate here. Can you elaborate or point to a reference? In another direction, do you mean to say that the space $M_{k+1/2}(N,\chi)$ (with $4|N$, $\chi $ modulo $4N$) is not defined properly?

Comment: I'm talking about the automorphic forms corresponding to the modular forms. Integral weight modular forms come from automorphic forms on $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ and the character $\chi$ corresponds to the central character. A reference might be Bump, Automorphic Forms and Representations. But for half integral weight modular forms, the meaning of $\chi$ is different: we "let" the theta function have trivial character. That's why it leads to complicated notions. See http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/modular_forms_of_half_integral_weight.pdf